# Share Fragment from external application

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I am creating an application with plugins architecture. I am discovering new plugins with `BroadcastReceiver` - if plugin is notified about introducing itself, it sends back name, data provider and preferences fragment's cannonical name (for example: `mobi.hsz.project.plugin.foo.FooFragment`)

I would like to adopt this fragment in my `PreferenceActivity` so if user clicks on plugin item in list - I would like to load this specified fragment. Is it event possible to load external fragment into my Fragment Manager ?

It works well if I pass new Intent from plugin and start it with `startActivity` in my application, however it breaks fragment design pattern.

The best solution is to start new intent inside some empty fragment, so it will looks like it's a part of my application but holds different application context. Can we display new intents inside fragment, not new 'window'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it event possible to load external fragment into my Fragment Manager ?

No, sorry.

> Can we display new intents inside fragment, not new 'window'?

Not in any sort of reliable fashion.

Comment: What about `ActivityGroup` ? Can we manage it to hold external intent's view ?

Comment: There was no question, sorry - `Deprecated since API level 13`.

Comment: @hsz: Even `ActivityGroup` did not work reliably across process boundaries. The only way one process can participate in another process' UI in a reliable fashion is via `RemoteViews`. That's certainly a possibility in a plugin environment, though whether it is worth the headache over just launching the plugin's desired configuration activity is up to you.